# Bold text jumps back to normal

Tags: css, fonts

I want to do some bold text on h1 on my wordpress-site. I have edited the CSS to use font-weight: bold but it seems to conflict with something else.

What happens is, on load it is bold but after load it jumps back to normal weighted text. Could anyone have a look at it:

http://www.norsktvthailand.net/windows/ ?

Stylesheet can be found at:

http://www.norsktvthailand.net/wp-content/themes/squirrel/style.css

Where am i going wrong? The text i want bold is the H1. I have also tried to use:

```
font-weight: bold !important;
```

to override other rules. But it seems to be a no-go..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use inspect element (Google Chrome), firebug (Firefox), developer tools (IE) to see how the render is changing the styles

Comment: I user the "inspect element" in google chrome. I see that my code for bolding the text is scored out. Is it supposed to comment why this happens? I dont have a clue why it does that. Could it be because of something else conflicting with my rule?

Comment: yes, just look at the last style that has the VALID property, it will probably lead you to know why is doing it, your issues might be due to a style (above or below) that is forcing the undesired change

Answer (score 0):

The page uses the [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) replacement technique, so the choice of font weight must be made when generating the Cufón code. From the CSS perspective, the heading is not displayed as text at all but by some routines external to CSS.

Comment: Oh, you are right! How did find that? I googled the themename with you suggestion "Coufon" and found this: http://www.inkthemes.com/supportforum/topic/remove-cufon-from-squirrel-theme . Youre a genious. I will test this later on. I kind of messed up the whole css while trying to get my H1 bold. Weak moment of stress. Will have to restore the CSS and give it a try.